# Почему не работает отправка AJAX запроса c JS на сервлет Java?

Tags: javascript, java, xmlhttprequest

Пытаюсь отправить JSON со страницы JS через обьект XMLHttpRequest(AJAX запрос) на сервлет Java, методом POST. Проблема в том - что запрос не приходит на сервер, не могу найти хорошую статью (главное АКТУАЛЬНУЮ) что бы почитать как отправлять, много где встречаются различные варианты отправки, путаница в голове. Подскажите в чём проблема ? Что я делаю не так?

```js
function sendDataForm(user){
    let json = JSON.stringify(user);
    console.log(json); 
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
    
            if (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 304) {
                console.log("OK"); 
            } else {
                alert("ERROR");
            }
    
        }
    }

    // xhr.responseType = "text";
    xhr.open("POST", "/mainservlet", true); 
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send(json);
}
```

```html
<section  id="sectionRegistration">
   <form id="formRegistration">
    <div class="paragraphForm">
     <label for="name"> Name: </label>
     <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="field"><br> 
    </div>
    
    <div class="paragraphForm">
     <label for="middleName">Middle name:</label>
     <input type="text" name="middleName" id="middleName" class="field">
    </div>

    <p class="paragraphForm">
     <label for="lastName">Last name:</label>
     <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" class="field">
    </p>

    <p class="paragraphForm">
     <label for="login">Desired Login:</label>
     <input type="text" name="login" id="login" class="field">
    </p>

    <p class="paragraphForm">
     <label for="password">Desired Password:</label>
     <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="field">
    </p>

    <p class="paragraphForm">
     <label for="repeatPassword">REPEAT Password:</label>
     <input type="password" name="repeatPassword" id="repeatPassword" class="field">
    </p>

    <p class="paragraphForm">
     <label for="email">Email:</label>
     <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="field">
    </p>

    <p class="paragraphForm">
     Role:
     <label for="roleOwner"> OWNER </label>
     <input type="radio" name="role" value="owner" id="roleOwner" class="fieldRadio field">

     <label for="roleForester"> FORESTER </label>
     <input type="radio" name="role" value="forester" id="roleForester" checked class="fieldRadio field">
    </p>

   </form>

   <!--ОТПРАВИТЬ-->
   <input class="buttonSend" type="submit" name="sendForm" value="Send >" id="registerButton">
   <!--НАЗАД-->
   <div class="buttonBack"><a href="systemPark.html"> Return Back </a></div>

   <!--DIV с ошибками из формы-->
   <div id="divWithErrors"></div>

  </section>
```

Comment: с клиента запрос уходит?

Comment: Как я понимаю да, во вкладке NetWork которая в Inspect, там указан путь верный к моему сервлету и статус ответа 404, JSON тоже верно выглядит

Comment: тогда ищите проблему на сервере

Comment: спасибо!) нашёл на сервере )

Answer (score 1):

не думаю что в этом причина, но заголовок у вас отправлен не верный

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

правильно будет

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
```

попробуйте указать полный путь, если 404 то путь к сервлету указан не верно

Comment: Спасибо, натолкнули на мысль !

Answer (score 1):

Только сейчас понял что не учёл артефакт, в котором дописал /systempark. Следовательно нужно было обращаться как:

xhr.open("POST", "/systempark/mainservlet", true);

Забыл я совсем про него.
Cпасибо тем, кто откликнулся)